# Como alterar ordem de aparição das Colunas em um Data Frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

eu tenho esse df montado no R:

```
                  Produto  Classificação Comun Quilo Indice
1           ABACAXI HAVAI       A GRAUDO  3,32   2,2      2
2           ABACAXI HAVAI        B MEDIO  2,81   1,8      3
3           ABACAXI HAVAI        C MIUDO  2,21   1,4      4
4             BANANA MACA              -   4,5     1      5
5         BANANA PRATA MG              -  3,13     1      6
6         BANANA PRATA SP              -  2,82     1      7
7   BANANA NANICA CLIMAT.              -  2,16     1     11
8              COCO VERDE              -  2,09   2,5      8
9            LARANJA LIMA    A (9/12 DZ)  2,46     1     12
10           LARANJA LIMA   B (13/15 DZ)  2,16     1     13
11           LARANJA LIMA   C (16/21 DZ)  1,97     1     14
12           LARANJA PERA    A (9/12 DZ)  2,84     1     15
13           LARANJA PERA   B (13/15 DZ)  2,63     1     16
14  MACA ESTRANG. RED DEL  80-163 FRUTOS  5,37     1     10
15     MACA NACIONAL FUJI 163-180 FRUTOS  5,31     1     17
16          MAMAO FORMOSA              A  2,99     1     18
17               UVA RUBI       ESPECIAL  3,48     1      9
18               MANDIOCA          MEDIA  1,83     1     19
21 TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND        EXTRA A     2     1     20
19        BATATA ESCOVADA       ESPECIAL  1,78     1     21
```

Eu gostaria de colocar a coluna "Indice" antes da coluna Produto, e deixar o resto na mesma ordem, como eu posso fazer isso?

Eu quero que fique assim:

```
   Indice             Produto  Classificação Comun Quilo 
1   2           ABACAXI HAVAI       A GRAUDO  3,32   2,2      
2   3           ABACAXI HAVAI        B MEDIO  2,81   1,8      
3   4           ABACAXI HAVAI        C MIUDO  2,21   1,4      
4   5             BANANA MACA              -   4,5     1      
5   6         BANANA PRATA MG              -  3,13     1      
6   7         BANANA PRATA SP              -  2,82     1      
7   11  BANANA NANICA CLIMAT.              -  2,16     1     
8   8              COCO VERDE              -  2,09   2,5     
9   12           LARANJA LIMA    A (9/12 DZ)  2,46     1     
10  13           LARANJA LIMA   B (13/15 DZ)  2,16     1     
11  14           LARANJA LIMA   C (16/21 DZ)  1,97     1     
12  15           LARANJA PERA    A (9/12 DZ)  2,84     1     
13  16           LARANJA PERA   B (13/15 DZ)  2,63     1     
14  10  MACA ESTRANG. RED DEL  80-163 FRUTOS  5,37     1     
15  17     MACA NACIONAL FUJI 163-180 FRUTOS  5,31     1     
16  18          MAMAO FORMOSA              A  2,99     1     
17  9                UVA RUBI       ESPECIAL  3,48     1     
18  19               MANDIOCA          MEDIA  1,83     1     
21  20 TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND        EXTRA A     2     1     
19  21        BATATA ESCOVADA       ESPECIAL  1,78     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que o data frame se chama `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
df_ordenado <- df %>%
  select(Indice, Produto, Classificação, Comun, Quilo)
df_ordenado
```

Comment: Aproveitando a pergunta, eu preciso pegar uma coluna no meio do DF e jogar para o fim, como faço ?

Answer (score 2):

Usando `everything()` para indicar as demais colunas que você não quer mudar. É mais prático para dataframes com muitas colunas.

```
library(dplyr)

df_ordenado <- df %>% select(Indice, Produto, everything())
df_ordenado
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando os mesmos nomes da resposta do @MarcusNunes, você também pode fazer com o R base:

```
df_ordenado <- df[c("Indice", "Produto", "Classificação", "Comun", "Quilo")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é usar a função `relocate`, do `dplyr`, construída para este fim:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  relocate(Indice)
```

Sua vantagem sobre `dplyr::select` é a de não precisar escrever todas as variáveis. Os argumentos `.before` e `.after` aumentam ainda mais a flexibilidade da função `relocate`.

Para maiores detalhes sobre essa função, clique [aqui](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-select-rename-relocate/).

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando, estou com uma tarefa parecida porém meu índice em alguns casos o cliente manda como nome um pouco diferente. Imaginem que no exemplo acima o nome indica foi escrito ind ou indice. Como posso ordenar pela posição do índice sem usar o cabeçalho ?

A ideia é ler a coluna índice e ordenar do Menor ou maior.